# Interval in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I try to use this query in hibernate, but i have problem with interval.

```
select * from table where timestampfield >= now()-interval 3 month;
```

Comment: NHibernate is supposed to use objects, not SQL queries...

Comment: can you post relevant code ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `INTERVAL` keyword is only valid inside a function such as `DATE_ADD()` or `DATE_SUB()`

```
select * from table where timestampfield >= DATE_SUB(now(), interval 3 month);
```